# how to search in array in react in laravel

Tags: reactjs, laravel

this my code , how to just return the only searched items on this meals[] array?

```
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        meals: [],
     };
    this.searchMeal = this.searchMeal.bind(this);

      }
```

this my search function but i don't know how to make it's work!

```
      searchMeal(event) {
     
        let search = event.target.value;
        let meals = this.state.mealsList;
        let mealsContent = [];
        if (search.length > 0) {
              // searched meals
        } else {
            // get meals if no results
            
        }
        this.setState({
            meals: mealsContent
        });
    }
```

Comment: can you show me array keys, or any examples of the array data?

Comment: my array has name , so i need to search by names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for example, you can use this code in your array

```
meals.map((meal, index) => {
                if (meal.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())) {
                    mealsContent.push(meal);
                }
            });
```

the final example is :

```
      searchMeal(event) {
 
    let search = event.target.value;
    let meals = this.state.mealsList;
    let mealsContent = [];
    if (search.length > 0) {
          // searched meals
           meals.map((meal, index) => {
                if (meal.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())) {
                    mealsContent.push(meal);
                }
            });
    } else {
        // get meals if no results
         this.getMeals();  // call your get meals function or call the old meals array
    }
    this.setState({
        meals: mealsContent
    });
}
```